# How to configure nginx with SSL?

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration

I am trying to configure ssl for the nginx load balancer , I see three different kinds of configuration files and I am not sure where the certificate and key file should be configured

These are

```
nginx/sites-available/default
nginx/sites-enabled/myDomain
nginx/nginx.conf
```

What are these configuration files? where should ssl be ideally configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't know a lot about Nginx. I would start with the docs.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/

**nginx/nginx.conf**
This is the main Nginx config file and should *not* contain site-specific configurations (like SSL)

**nginx/sites-available/default**
This is where you configure your site (and your SSL settings). The default config is simply named "default".

**nginx/sites-enabled/myDomain**
This is the location that Nginx looks in for sites to serve to users. Typically, you create a symlink from here to the sites-available directory, like below.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourconfig /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

This allows you to easily activate/deactivate sites by just adding/removing a symlink.